# SQL 2016 Clustered Install - SlipStream - Updates not Shown

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, installation

Attempting to install SQL 2016 with the latest SP and CU.

Running the following (from the directory with the Install exe):

```
setup.exe /Action= InstallFailoverCluster /UpdateEnabled=TRUE /UpdateSource= "D:\Software\SQLServer2016_Updates"
```

The GUI starts and the Product Updates step is shown but nothing is displayed.

Note that when attempting to do this as a standalone install ie Action=Install, the SP and CU are shown in the GUI.

Any thoughts (short of creating a full config file)?

Comment: You have "fancy quotes" around the UpdateSource path--if that was a straight copy/paste from the command you are running then that might be the problem.

Comment: ...er, I meant “fancy quotes.”

Comment: Ha, yes, good spot - though thankfully they didn't make it to the command line (deleted and replaced)- so unfortunately, that's not the issue.

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug as I'm seeing lots of blog posts from over the years using the same switches.  If you have a MS support agreement you might open an incident--they should be able to repro it easily.  Wish I had test servers that I could use to repro it...

Comment: Thanks Tony - a bug was my thought as standalone finds them fine.